# How do i refresh WebBrowser1 whitout flickering on VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

> I call my page every 20 seconds but when i call my page i see a flash. Is it possible to avoid the flickering when the page load?

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri("http://metalrockpopradio.caramania.com/tuneefy4.php"))
Dim timer As New Timer()
timer.Interval = 20000
AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf WebBrowser1.Refresh
timer.Start()
```

Comment: Side note:  That timer needs to be declared at the form level in order for the garbage collector to dispose of it later.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with loading the page every 20 seconds?  That's rarely the best option.

Comment: `AddressOf WebBrowser1.Refresh` is weird. You are calling the Refresh method of the WebBrowser that way. Did you mean do write `Sub() WebBrowser1.Refresh`?

Comment: I have an internet radio. I need to refresh for the new album art appears in WebBrowser1

Comment: But, is this refresh performed to just show an image? If so, you could just download the image and show it in some control.

Comment: Yes show an image but when the artist change i need the image change also

Comment: Right, but that `php` just sets a `<img src="" (...) />`. You can just download that image every 20 seconds or when its the *right time* and show it in a PictureBox. You know that the `PictureBox.Load()` method supports `https` (URL as strings, actually) sources.

Comment: Can you provide to me an exemple of code i'm new...

Comment: i took your code for picturebox2 but now it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

- Create a Form (here called `Form1`)
- add a PictureBox (here, called `PictureBox1`) to it
- set the PictureBox size to what you want and set its `SizeMode = Zoom`
- paste the following code inside the Form's code partial file (F7 on the Form)

---

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Dim timer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Private client As WebClient = New WebClient()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RefreshImage(Nothing, Nothing)
        timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
        AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf Me.RefreshImage
        timer.Interval = 5000
        timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub RefreshImage(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim HttpResource As String = client.DownloadString("http://metalrockpopradio.caramania.com/tuneefy4.php")
        Dim ParseStart As Integer = HttpResource.IndexOf("=") + 2
        HttpResource = HttpResource.Substring(ParseStart, HttpResource.LastIndexOf(ChrW(34)) - ParseStart)
        If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Load(HttpResource)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        client.Dispose()
        timer.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: i have 2 WebBrowser but when i do it for the other one i have errors

Comment: There are no WebBrowsers here (this code). What are these two WebBrowsers you're referring to doing? If you have some error notifications somewhere, you need to specify which erros and when they occur, otherwise it's quite difficult to suggest something meaningful.

Comment: i have another picturebox2 but i have errors when i try to put your code in

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But, which errors? Can you update your question with the code you're using now so I can see what's what?

Comment: i use your code for picturebox2 but i have errors because i use similar terms

Comment: You really need to show that code. Do you see the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53964252/edit) link under your question? Click that link and you can modify/update your question. Post the code that's causing the errors you're mentioning so I can see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have two of them.  When the new reload is done, show the new control and hide the old.

Alternatively, use AJAX or similar on your page to reload content.

Comment: Can you explain more because i'm new in VB.NET. Or an example?

Comment: do you have an example?