# Is it possible to load php result (echo) in PictureBox?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    MyBase.Load
    RefreshImage1(Nothing, Nothing)
    timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
    AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf Me.RefreshImage1
    timer.Interval = 20000
    timer.Start()
End Sub

Protected Sub RefreshImage1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim HttpResource As String =  client.DownloadString("http://metalrockpopradio.caramania.com/3

 .php")
    Dim ParseStart As Integer = HttpResource.IndexOf("=") + 2
    HttpResource = HttpResource.Substring(ParseStart,   HttpResource.LastIndexOf(ChrW(34)) - ParseStart)
    If PictureBox5.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox5.Image.Dispose()
    PictureBox5.Load(HttpResource)
    PictureBox5.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As  



FormClosedEventArgs)  Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    client.Dispose()
    timer.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

> I changed picturebox4 for picturebox5 but for form1 it says i have multiple instances of form1 and when i change for form2 nothing in the picturebox. The problem is strange and i donT know how to resolve it.
>   Can you help me i need it and after i will can publish my solution...
>   I tried every things but nothing works.

Comment: It is a web page that *contains* an image.  Which is located elsewhere.  Digging it out is not difficult, that's not a complicated web page.  Use your browser's Web Developer tools to see that.

Comment: [Already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53965102/7444103). This code show an image loading it from a `Http` resource. What is the problem then, since it's already working?

Comment: The code works for 1 picturebox but when i try the code for second picturebox it's not working...

Comment: Of course it works for just one PictureBox, the target control is `PictureBox4`. Did you add/change the name of the second PictureBox you want to target?

Comment: yes i did but don't works

Comment: Well, where's the code that loads the image in the second (first?) PictureBox? Post all the code you're using to load the images.

Comment: Where is this `PictureBox5`? In `Form1` or in `Form2`? The current code (the one you updated) is set to work on a Form called `Form1` and it supposes that `Form1` contains a PictureBox named `PictureBox5`. Is this your scenario? Take the required time to explain what you have and post the exact errors you receive, not a summary or interpretation  of them. Post an image of the Form(s) if you think it can better explain your setup.

Comment: PictureBox5 is in form1 . I changed RefreshImage1 for RefreshImage2. It says Form1 has many instances.

Comment: If *Form1 has many instances* then you're doing something wrong (like creating multiple instances of that Form) which is not related to th code you're currently showing. If you need to update more than one PictureBox in the same Form at the same time, just add that reference in the `RefreshImage` hanlder: `If PictureBox5.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox5.Image.Dispose()  If PictureBox4.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox4.Image.Dispose() PictureBox5.Load(HttpResource) PictureBox4.Load(HttpResource)` for example.

Comment: Many instances of RefreshImage1, Many instances of Form1

Comment: What i do with 2 urls? Dim HttpResource As String = client.DownloadString("http://metalrockpopradio.caramania.com/3.php")                      Dim HttpResource As String = client.DownloadString("http://metalrockpopradio.caramania.com/tuneefy4.php")

Comment: Download one string from one Http address and assing the result of the elaboration to  the first PictureBox, then download another string and assign the result to another PictureBox. If you use the same string (`HttpResource`) `Dim` it just once, of course.

Comment: is it possible to load image from last fm? I'm using Shoutcast